# How to use anyOf on different properties type?

Tags: jsonschema

In the schema below, I need `items_list`, `price` and `variance` as required keys. Condition is `price` and `variance` may or may not be null but both cannot be null.

Though I'm able to achieve it, I'm looking forward to if there's any shorter way to do this. Also, I'm not sure where exactly to put `required` and `additionalProperties` keys.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "items_list": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
    },
    "anyOf": [
        {
            "properties": {
                "price": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": 0,
                },
                "variance": {
                    "type": [
                        "number",
                        "null"
                    ],
                    "minimum": 0,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            "properties": {
                "price": {
                    "type": [
                        "number",
                        "null"
                    ],
                    "minimum": 0,
                },
                "variance": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "minimum": 0,
                },
            },
        },
    ],
    # "required": [
    #     "items_list",
    #     "price",
    #     "variance",
    # ],
    # "additionalProperties": False,
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question, "can it be shorter?", the answer is, yes. The general rule of thumb is to never *define* anything in the boolean logic keywords. Use the boolean logic keywords only to add compound constraints. I use the term "compound constraint" to mean a constraint that is based on more that one value in a schema. In this case, the compound constraint is that price and variance can't both be null.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "items_list": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "type": "string" }
    },
    "price": { "type": ["number", "null"], "minimum": 0 },
    "variance": { "type": ["number", "null" ], "minimum": 0 }
  },
  "required": ["items_list", "price", "variance"],
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "allOf": [{ "$ref": "#/definitions/both-price-and-variance-cannot-be-null" }],
  "definitions": {
    "both-price-and-variance-cannot-be-null": {
      "not": {
        "properties": {
          "price": { "type": "null" },
          "variance": { "type": "null" }
        },
        "required": ["price", "variance"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not only do you not have to jump through hoops to get `additionalProperties` working properly, it's also easier to read. It even matches your description of the problem, "price and variance may or may not be null" (`properties`) but "both cannot be null" (`not` (compound constraint)). You could make this even shorter by inlining the definition, but I included it to show how expressive this technique can be while still being shorter than the original schema.

Comment: This is definitely easier to read and understand, also, explains the requirement better.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have this mostly right. That's the right place to put `required`.

Using `additionalProperties: false`, you need to also define `properties` at the top level, `additionalProperties` cannot "see through" `*Of` keywords (applicators).

You can add `properties: [prop] : true`, but define all the properties.
You need to do this because `additionalProperties` only knows about `properties` within the same schema object at the same level.

Comment: Interesting detail about the `additionalProperties` keyword. Do you happen to have a resource backing that up? So far I only encountered this kind of “only in the same sub-schema” clause in relation to `if`/`then`/`else`.

Comment: I looked up more into `additionalProperties` and found [this draft](https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-handrews-json-schema-02#section-9.3.2.3) that states "The behavior of this keyword depends on the presence and annotation results of "properties" and "patternProperties" within the same schema object."
Also, pointing to [this discussion](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/issues/668#issuecomment-593549261), worth knowing.

Comment: I'm one of the team that work on the spec document itself. That is indeed the source. It's worth noting though that the link you provided is draft `2019-09` as opposed to `draft-07`, for anyone reading the document, and reading about other keywords. Support for draft `2019-09` is growing!